# 8 bit counter from T Flip Flops

Tags: verilog, flipflop, counter, circuit-design, quartus

I'm trying to build an 8bit counter in Verilog. I specifically need to create a module that I instantiate 8 times. I have followed the diagram below (and assumed that I can just build on it to make it 8 instead of 4 bits). It appears what I have built instead is a shift register, it can shift ones and zeros - instead of 0001 -> 0011 I need 0001 -> 0010 (duh!). I feel as though I have misinterpreted the circuit diagram, as my logic seems otherwise sound. Any help much appreciated!

[image: 4 bit counter]

TFlipFlop:

```
module tflfl(t, clk, clr, q);

input t;
input clk;
input clr;
output reg q;


always@(posedge clk, negedge clr)
    begin
        if(~clr)
            q <= 1'b0;
        else
            q <= t;
    end

endmodule
```

Modular Implementation:

```
tflfl t1(.t(enable), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q0));    
tflfl t2(.t(q0), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q1));
tflfl t3(.t(q1 && q0), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q2));
tflfl t4(.t(q2 && q1 && q0), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q3));
tflfl t5(.t(q3 && q2 && q1 && q0), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q4));
tflfl t6(.t(q4 && q3 && q2 && q1 && q0), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q5));
tflfl t7(.t(q5 && q4 && q3 && q2 && q1 && q0), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q6));
tflfl t8(.t(q6 && q5 && q4 && q3 && q2 && q1 && q0), .clk(clock), .clr(reset), .q(q7));
```

Comment: I see your code is not strictly following the diagram. The `T` if `t1` should be `q0 & enable`. And of the others it should be `and` of two inputs only, not incremental. And suddenly you will see a pattern, which will make it easy to define a generic N-bit counter using generate loops...

Comment: Your TFF is written with the functionality of a DFF.

Comment: @eugenesh. Do you mean the T in t2? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your schematic shows a T-type flip-flop, which toggles when its input is high. Your rtl code, on the other hand, implements a regular D-type flip-flop. Your module should instead read:

```
always@(posedge clk, negedge clr)
begin
    if(~clr)
        q <= 1'b0;
    else
        q <= q ^ t;
end
```

By XOR'ing the output with the input, you will toggle the state when t is high, creating a T-type flip-flop.

The module instantiation is also different from the schematic. Your t inputs are all missing the `&& enable` that the leftmost AND gate in the schematic implements.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an 8bit binary counter being built? Like 0000 0001 -> 0000 0010 -> 0000 0011 -> ?

Should it be specifically done only with T Flip Flops only?

May be a JK FF chain. Pull all the J&K high. Clock to the first FF. Connect the Q outputs directly to the clocks of consecutive FFs (If it's ~Clock input) Otherwise use ~Q output to clock.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram is shift 1: (reset) 000 -> 100 -> 110 -> 111 -> 111

Comment: Look again: The "non-clock" input is not labelled `D`, but `T`.